# Install Team Foundation Server with Remote SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I am in the process of evaluating TFS 2010.  I am trying to install onto our application server which sits in a domain and runs Windows 2008 R2 Standard.

We already have a SQL Server in place on a separate Windows 2008 box that I want to use - this is in the same domain.

After installing TFS, I am using the Advanced Configuration Wizard to try and complete the setup.  There are 3 bits that are reporting errors : "Database" and "Reporting".

When I enter the SQL Server details, TFS gives me this error :

```
TF255049: A connection cannot be made to the server that is running SQL Server. Verify that you have entered the correct name for the server, including the instance name, that the server you attempting to connect to is online, and that you have required permissions to connect... (it goes on a bit more)
```

The server I have installed TFS on is a web server that runs several .Net websites - all of which can connect to the SQL Server with no problem.

I have tried IP Address, machine name, instance name - all report the same error.

Has anybody been in this situation before?

**EDIT :** Strangely if I go to the "Reporting Server" page in the wizard and enter the SQL Server name, it connects correctly in order to get the Report Server URL and Report Manager URL.  So it seems this maybe user account related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things spring to mind:

You'll need to make sure the TFS service accounts have permissions on the DB server.

If Windows Firewall is on on the TFS box, switch it off for a minute or two and try again.

If that solves it, turn it back on and open the SQL ports.

HTH

Comment: Windows Firewall is turned off. I created a local Windows user on both servers called "tfsuser".  Does the user need to be a Windows Admin?

Comment: Doesn't need to be an admin but needs to be added as a login in SQL server. I usually give it sql admin rights. (Sure this can be tighter but not sure which level so quoting what I know works)

Comment: In the end I had to use an AD account and add the AD account as a sys_admin in SQL Server.  Like you say probably overkill but it works!